# want a list<ABC> be converted to MAP<var, List<ABC>>

Tags: java, guava

Is there any guava utility which can convert LIST to MAP>. (var is a property of Objects.
I have a list , ABC  has a variable var in it. I want to create a map so that all the ABC objects having same var value should be clubbed in a list and so i should be able to get list of ABC having same var value. But i want to use some guava utility for this. I don't want to use regalar foreach block to populate this.

Comment: I recommend http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is very easy with Java 8. Does it have to be guava?

Comment: @PaulBoddington Unfortunately in my project we are still not using java 8

Comment: Ok, well I don't know guava well, but I do know it has an interface called `ListMultimap` that I think does what you want. I'd google it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for [`Multimaps.index(Iterable<ABC>, Function<? super ABC, ? extends T>)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function)), which would give you an `ImmutableListMultimap<T, ABC>`.

You can then call `ImmutableListMultimap.asMap()` to get it as a `Map<T, List<ABC>` (or maybe it would be a `Map<T, Collection<ABC>>`, actually - but the collections would be lists).